# Counting similar ints in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Is there a stl function for vector that will allow me to find the number of elements in a vector? For example if I was looking for the count of ints 4 in this vector:

```
vector<ACard> PairFinder;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
Pairfinder[i] = rand()%5+1
}
```

Comment: Is `Acard` a typedef for `int` ? Also use `push_back` or pre-allocate side for `PathFinder`

Answer (score 2):

You want [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count):

```
#include <algorithm>

int n = std::count(PairFinder.begin(), PairFinder.end(), 4);
```

If you cannot easily represent the value type you're looking for, you can use the variant `std::count_if` to specify a custom predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easy, using [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) from the `algorithm` header:

```
int fours = std::count(PairFinder.begin(), PairFinder.end(), 4);
```